# Slickgrid select row on right click before displaying context menu

Tags: slickgrid

Using this I can display a menu by right clicking a cell:

```
// right click context menu
grid.onContextMenu.subscribe(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
  //grid.setSelectedRows(cell.row);
  $("#contextMenu")
      .data("row", cell.row)
      .css("top", e.pageY)
      .css("left", e.pageX)
      .show();
  $("body").one("click", function () {
    $("#contextMenu").hide();
  });
});
```

However I would like the row to be selected, both as visual confirmation that the correct row has been right-clicked, and because some of the menu items use the selected row for their functions.

This:

```
grid.setSelectedRows(cell.row);
```

doesn't work. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be as simple as the fact that `setSelectedRows` takes an array of row indexes.
Try

```
grid.setSelectedRows([cell.row]);
```